# C error: expected '=', ',', ';',

Tags: c

Im working on a PIC24f microcontroller, writing a C code for communication protocol.Im facing an error in function Reade2PW. I thought uint16_t gives the problem so i changed the 
"uint16_t" to "int16" & "int16_t" and compiled but the problem is still remains the same i.e it gives the same error. My MPLAB using XC16
compiler. I read XC16 user guide, it can support uint16_t and int16_t.
Here is the screenclip from the XC16 user guide.

[image]

How to solve this problem? Your valuable suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
    {
        ..
        ..
        return 0;
    }

unsigned uint16_t Reade2PW(unsigned uint16_t rde2pw) //Error here
        {   
            unsigned uint16_t EEPVal;
            unsigned char i, *Ptr;
            ....
        }
void SaveE2PW(unsigned uint16_t rde2pw, unsigned uint16_t Cx)//Error here
       {    
            unsigned char i, *Ptr;
            ..
       }
```

Error Description:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Reade2PW'
error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'rde2pw'
```

Comment: `unsigned uint16_t` --> `uint16_t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have duplicate type specifiers in both your functions:

```
unsigned uint16_t Reade2PW(unsigned uint16_t rde2pw) //Error here
^^duplicate types here      ^^ and here
```

Remove one. The `uint16_t` is already unsigned (so the `u` prefix). So just remove the `unsigned` from them:

```
uint16_t Reade2PW(uint16_t rde2pw)
        {   
            uint16_t EEPVal;
          // ....
        }
```